# User Profile Picture Cached After Change

Tags: 6

When changing your profile picture (using core pictures support) the image is uploaded correctly but is saved with the same file path as the old image.

The result is even though the image is uploaded correctly, the browser has cached the old one and still displays it, making it seem as though the new picture wasn't uploaded.

Forcing a refresh <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> resolves the problem, but this is not normal user behavior and has already caused confusion.

Is there a way to force a reload for this, for example changing the image path or setting an expires header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point! It's easy to change the default behavior, however, with a module roughly along these lines:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (variable_get('user_pictures', 0))
     $form['#validate'][] = '_YOUR_MODULE_user_validate_picture';
}

function _YOUR_MODULE_user_validate_picture(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $source = $form_state['values']['picture'];
  if (! empty($source)) {
    $destination = /* TODO: generated random filename */;
    file_move($source, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
  }
}
```

Or, even better, use the [Unique Avatar](http://drupal.org/project/unique_avatar) module. :-)

Comment: Unique Avatar did the trick

Answer (score 3):

use a random tail after the filename like 
http://www.domain.com/filename**?122492834932** 
it will detect your file as a new file and browser cache will not read it as the same as the old one